# What do you think about phone number input field’s width in web design? Is it important whether the number is long or not?

Tags: forms, design, input, phone-numbers

I'm designing a new form field for sign up page and something disturbs me. I have to show **phone number** field but I don't want to make it wider than phone number's length. I realize most web sites don't take care of the width and they try to fit other inputs (such as name, email etc.)

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to worry about is making user aware of your expectations. I often see registration forms that once submitted ask you to input your phone number again, but this time in the right format. Some don't even bother mentioning what the correct format it.

Here is a good form example for you:

[image]

Link: https://web.telegram.org/#/login

Answer (score 1):

**In my point of view**, it's preferably chosen by either **restrictions** or **considerations** of many related issue(s) simultaneously. Like being adaptive for mobility, design concept, development capabilities, the length of the form, etc.

As I suppose, most of the websites have fixed input length because of the symmetrical concerns leading to their **`design aspects`**. It's a common use case while there are comparably less (2 to 5 mostly) input box displayed together like a sign up form or similar forms.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbgQS6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Hence, if it's not the case, you probably have a bigger form where your users need to fill a detailed personal information. In this case, you probably don't see any example displaying all same sizes of inputs.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6JEXu.png)</sup>

> Even you haven't visualized your exact output here, I think it mostly depends on the preference,
>
> - of symmetrical concerns (design simplicity)
> - restrictions on the space saved to display the form
> - even because of the incapable developers designed that page

You may feel free to display the outlook of your own choice yet considering the limitations of your circumstances.